# He was born into a once-proud family. (What's the meaning?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> He was born into a once-proud family.

What's the meaning of, especially, "a once-proud family."?

Comment: The use of **once** in this fashion means **formerly**. They are no longer proud. This you could have easily established for yourself by googling the word.

Comment: @Ronald Sole What's the meaning of the sentence? Could you rephrase the sentence?

Comment: Have you checked 'once' in a dictionary?

Comment: The family he was born into had been proud (presumably of their high status) at an earlier period (before he was born).

Comment: @KateBuning 'high status' would mean 'rich and/or socially/professionally high position'?

Comment: You copied my name incorrectly, so I only spotted your question by chance. Is there any context for the sentence? The family could have been impoverished aristocrats, or formerly rich and successful people who had lost their money.

Comment: Sorry for typo for your name. No context. Thx for your comment.

Comment: When I type '@' followed by the first letter of a poster's ID, the rest of the word comes up automatically and I can click on it. Getting the ID right is the only way to flag up that there is a personal reply for a poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Once', can mean 'at some time in the past', either on one occasion, or for a continuous period.

'Proud' in this sense, could mean 'standing out', as in the case of a family of great wealth, fame, or power, or equally, that the family had great pride in their position.

So, 'once-proud' means a family who at one time stood out for some reason, but no longer does.

Comment: I would dispute that _proud_ means _standing out_ here. It means _having or showing a high or excessively high opinion of oneself or one's importance_ (Oxford Languages).

Comment: @KateBunting I absolutely agree that it could mean that, but I feel it could simply mean well known (i.e. standing out, as in: "the stone stood proud of the grassland"). I'll edit the answer to reflect the two possibilities. Thanks.